# How do I find out what causes space on an element? margin and padding?

Tags: php, html, css

Okay, I have a page where posts are echoed and the post text seems to have padding on the top and bottom, and I don't want it to... Help?

**CSS**

```
.viewpost {
    margin-bottom:25px;
    width:80%;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 5px solid white;
    display:inline-block;
    }

p.viewpost {
    display:none;
}
```

**PHP**

```
  echo '<div class="viewpost">';
  if(!empty($row['post'])) {
  echo '<p class="">' . $row['post'] . '</p>';
  echo '</div><br />';
```

[image: The post page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `padding: 0` and possibly `margin: 0` on whatever markup needs it. Browsers apply default styles. I use a CSS reset at the start of my documents to be sure I don't have problems like that.

You have a default top and bottom margin on all `p` tags on that page. I over-rode it for those elements using:

```
.viewpost p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

There's also a slight padding. You could add `padding: 0` also, but some amount of space is nice..

To help you in the future: just right click the element and "inspect". You can then click through the dom tree and look at that element and every related element and they get highlighted. The highlighting shows you where the spacing comes from. You can then look at all the styles on the element to see what the margin/padding rules are and where they are set (what file, line).

Comment: @user2544765 are you able to link the page? I could inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

The padding and margin are on your paragraphs:

```
.viewpost p{margin:0;padding:0;}
```